# difficulty in deploying struts 2 application

Tags: eclipse, struts2

I am a beginner with struts2 and I have few struts2 projects downloaded from a website, but they all are created as simple java projects and not as web-projects, so I am unable to deploy them on my Tomcat or JBoss AS server through Eclipse.

How can simple java projects be deployed on a Java EE server?

Comment: What IDE are you using? There are three things to do: 1) Understand how to create a new web project appropriate for your IDE. 2) Follow the getting started guide (http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4.1/docs/how-to-create-a-struts-2-web-application.html) try to go with the maven build. 3) Your IDE will create a WAR file (and may even deploy it for you), you need to upload this war file following the instructions of your webserver. So where among these steps are you?

Comment: Hey thanks, I created a structure similar to the one shown on website and manually added all the files required and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a structure similar to the one shown on website and manually added all the files required and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is download [sample applications](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi#struts2341) from Struts2 official sites and deploy them on any of the server of your choice.
Those sample application comes with all required dependencies as well will give you idea about structuring of S2 application as well flow and configurations